# Tkinter in python- why can I not create text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a canvas c that I drew a graph on, and now I want to label the points of the graph. For whatever reason, the graph is working, but not the labels.

```
countries = starcoords.keys() #returns a list of all the countries I want to work with
for i in countries: #this part works
    (xcor1, ycor1) = starcoords[i][1] #basically, returns the coordinates of the country i'm working with
    for j in starcoords[i][2]: #starcoords[key][2] is a list of all the countries it connects to, then it goes through and draws lines to each country
        (xcor2, ycor2) = starcoords[j][1]
        if starcoords[i][0] == starcoords[j][0]:
            continent = starcoords[i][0]
            continentcolour = clustercoords[continent][0]
            c.create_line(xcor1, ycor1, xcor2, ycor2, fill=continentcolour,width=2, activefill='#900')
        else:
            c.create_line(xcor1, ycor1, xcor2, ycor2, fill="grey",width=2,activefill='#900')

for i in countries: #for whatever reason this part doesn't
    (xcor1, ycor1) = starcoords[i][1]
    print(xcor1,ycor1)
    c.create_text(xcor1, ycor1,fill='grey')
```

as you can see, the first for-loop basically draws lines to each country it is connected to, and selects the color based on whether its part of the same continent. I'm not sure why c.create_line is working and c.create_text is not

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. How do we know if that second `for i` loop is part of the function or part of something else (or part of the other for loop...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
c.create_text(xcor1, ycor1,fill='grey')
```

You do not specify a `text` argument, so no text is drawn.

Try:

```
for i in countries:
    (xcor1, ycor1) = starcoords[i][1]
    c.create_text(xcor1, ycor1,fill='grey', text=i) 
    #...assuming `i` is a string containing the name of the country
```